# Heroku - NodeJS Application Error

Tags: node.js, heroku

I deployed the app through `github`, and all went fine. But when i open the website appears:

**Application Error**

> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

```
If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

My `heroku` log:

```
2016-04-22T10:26:03.321608+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-04-22T10:26:03.321598+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-04-22T10:26:04.121512+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-04-22T10:26:13.903416+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-04-22T10:26:16.220624+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-04-22T10:26:16.220639+00:00 app[web.1]: > Bustabit@2.0.0 start /app
2016-04-22T10:26:16.220641+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server/index
2016-04-22T10:26:16.220642+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-04-22T10:26:16.646330+00:00 app[web.1]: fs.js:549
2016-04-22T10:26:16.646366+00:00 app[web.1]:   return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
2016-04-22T10:26:16.646390+00:00 app[web.1]:                  ^
2016-04-22T10:26:16.646392+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-04-22T10:26:16.646392+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/config/build-config.json'
2016-04-22T10:26:16.646393+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Error (native)
2016-04-22T10:26:16.646394+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:549:18)
2016-04-22T10:26:16.646394+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:397:15)
2016-04-22T10:26:16.646395+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/config/config.js:9:30)
2016-04-22T10:26:16.646395+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
2016-04-22T10:26:16.646396+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
2016-04-22T10:26:16.646396+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
2016-04-22T10:26:16.646397+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
2016-04-22T10:26:16.646397+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
2016-04-22T10:26:16.646399+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
2016-04-22T10:26:16.654518+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

I know that a file is missing. But in which file does it calls the missing file?

```
2016-04-22T14:22:03.876529+00:00 app[web.1]: fs.js:549
2016-04-22T14:22:03.876540+00:00 app[web.1]:   return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
2016-04-22T14:22:03.876563+00:00 app[web.1]:                  ^
2016-04-22T14:22:03.876567+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:397:15)
2016-04-22T14:22:03.876568+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/config/config.js:9:30)
2016-04-22T14:22:03.876604+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
2016-04-22T14:22:03.892638+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v4.4.3
2016-04-22T14:22:03.894323+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-04-22T14:22:03.895519+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-04-22T14:22:03.324528+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

New error. What's happening this time?

Comment: My guess is the '/app/config/build-config.json' is missing at the same time the file path some where you specified is not being recognized by the program

Comment: have you find out a way why its always looking folders under app folder are we changes default folder or have you find any solution? Thank yoıu

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's throwing the error from the file '/app/config/config.js', line 9.

Comment: Now it's looking for 'build-config.json' but can't find that.